# Error en listbox.selection con Python y Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

hice un programa que tiene 3 listbox. Luego para agregar un producto hice un if que usa una cuenta de los primeros 2 listboxs, y un elif del otro. El problema es que no se cumple ese elif, sino que lo toma el primer if.
La idea es que se seleccione un rubro de esas 3 listas. Despues que si se selecciona de la lista1 o 2, pase por un lado, y si se selecciona de la 3, pase por el otro.

```
        # ListsBoxs
    self.listbox1 = Listbox(frame, width=35, height=28)
    activos = ['Caja', 'Banco', 'Valores a depositar','Moneda extranjera',"Fondo fijo", "Titulos y acciones", "Deudores varios","Deudores por venta","Deudores morosos","Deudores en litigio","Documentos a cobrar", "Concepto pagado poadelantado", "Hipotecas a cobrar","Anticipios proveedores", "Accionistas", "Mercaderias", "Materias primas", "Productos en proceso de elaboracion","Productos terminados", "Rodados", "Instalaciones", "Muebles y utiles", "Inmuebles", "Maquinarias", "Llave de negocio", "Marcas y patentes", "Derechos de autor", "Gastos de organizacion"]
    self.listbox1.insert(0, *activos)
    self.listbox1.grid(row=3, column=0)


    self.listbox2 = Listbox(frame, width=35, height=28)
    pasivos = ["Proveedores", "Acreedores varios", "Documentos a pagar", "Intereses a pagar", "Obligaciones negociables", "Prestamos a pagar", "Acreedores prendarios e hipotecarios", "Adelantos en cuenta corriente", "Honorarios a pagar", "Sueldos a pagar", "Anses a pagar", "Retencion impuesto a las ganancias", "Retencion IVA", "Dividendos", "Concepto cobrado por adelantado", "Anticipo de clientes", "Cuentas por pagar", "Previsiones"]
    self.listbox2.insert(0, *pasivos)
    self.listbox2.grid(row=3, column=1)

    self.listbox3 = Listbox(frame, width=35, height=28)
    resultados = ['Gastos Luz','Descuento obtenido','Descuento otorgado','Interes otorgado','Interes obtenido', 'Ventas','CMV', 'Alquileres cobrados', 'Comision Cobrada', 'Impuestos', 'Alquileres pagados', 'Sueldos y jornales', 'Gastos generales', 'Comisiones pagadas', 'Publicidad', 'Seguros']
    self.listbox3.insert(0, *resultados)
    self.listbox3.grid(row=3, column=2)



    def add_product(self):
    try:
        if (rows:= self.listbox1.selection_get() or self.listbox2.selection_get()):
            query = 'INSERT INTO balance (id, cuenta, debe, haber) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parameters = (self.nro_cuenta.get(), rows, self.price_debe.get(), self.price_haber.get())
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            self.price_debe.delete(0, END)
            self.price_debe.insert(0, int(0))
            self.price_haber.delete(0, END)
            self.price_haber.insert(0, int(0))
            self.nro_cuenta.delete(0, END)
            self.mesagge['text'] = 'Se guardo con exito'
        elif (rows:= self.listbox3.selection_get()):
            query = 'INSERT INTO balance (id, cuenta, debe, haber) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parameters = (self.nro_cuenta.get(), rows, self.price_debe.get(), self.price_haber.get())
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            self.price_debe.delete(0, END)
            self.price_haber(0, END)
            self.nro_cuenta.delete(0, END)
            self.mesagge['text'] = 'Resultado de ejercicio guardado'
        else:
            self.mesagge['text'] = 'No hay rubro'
    except (sqlite3.IntegrityError, TclError):
        self.mesagge['text'] = 'No hay datos o ya esta cargado'
```

Comment: ¿Que modo se seleccion tiene tus listboxs (browse, single, multiple o extended)? ¿La idea es obtener las filas seleccionadas de ambas (listbox1 y listbox2) en su conjunto o solo de listbox1 si tiene algo seleccionado y si no lo tiene de listbox2 ?

Comment: Ahi edite la publicacion con los detalles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `selection_get` no es un método propio de `ListBox`, es común a todos los widgets que exporten al sistema X o al clipboard en Windows lo seleccionado. No tienes forma de saber que widgets exportó ese texto, de hecho podría no ser ni de una de tus `ListBox` si interactuás entre medias con otro widget que también exporte su selección.

Puedes obtener el item de una `ListBox` con `listbox.get(indice)`. Para obtener el índice no puedes usar `tk.ACTIVE` porque aunque hagas click en otra lista la primera seguirá teniendo uno activo. Lo que puedes usar es `listbox.curselection`. Esto nos genera otro problema, si todas las listas pierden el foco no habrá nada seleccionado.

Yo suelo enfocar ésto creando una clase personalizada que permita agrupar varias listbox de forma que solo un item pueda estar seleccionado de entre todas, además de facilitar la obtención del item en si:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self._widgets = []

    def add_widget(self, widget_instance):
        if widget_instance not in self._widgets:
            self._widgets.append(widget_instance)

    def remove_widget(self, widget_instance):
        try:
            self._widgets.remove(widget_instance)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    def __contain__(self, obj):
        return obj in self._widgets

    def __iter__(self):
        self._index = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            widget = self._widgets[self._index]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration()
        self._index += 1
        return widget



class GroupListbox(tk.Listbox):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, group=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.configure(exportselection=False)
        self.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self._on_select)
        self._group = None
        self.group = group or Group()
        self.selected_row = None

    def _on_select(self, _):
        if csel:= self.curselection():
            self.selected_row = self.get(csel)
            if self.group is not None:
                for child in self.group:
                    if child is not self:
                        child.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
                        child.selected_row = None
    @property
    def group(self):
        return self._group

    @group.setter
    def group(self, group):
        if group is None:
            if self._group is not None:
                self._group.remove_widget(self) 
                self.group = Group()

        elif not isinstance(group, Group):
            raise ValueError(
                f"{self.__name__}.group debe ser una instancia de Group o None"
                )
        else:
            self._group = group
            self.group.add_widget(self)


class Test(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        frame = self
        lb_group = Group()
        self.listbox1 = GroupListbox(frame, width=35, height=28, group=lb_group)
        activos = ['Caja', 'Banco', 'Valores a depositar','Moneda extranjera',
                    "Fondo fijo", "Titulos y acciones", "Deudores varios",
                    "Deudores por venta","Deudores morosos","Deudores en litigio",
                    "Documentos a cobrar", "Concepto pagado poadelantado",
                    "Hipotecas a cobrar","Anticipios proveedores", "Accionistas",
                    "Mercaderias", "Materias primas",
                    "Productos en proceso de elaboracion","Productos terminados",
                    "Rodados", "Instalaciones", "Muebles y utiles", "Inmuebles",
                    "Maquinarias", "Llave de negocio", "Marcas y patentes",
                    "Derechos de autor", "Gastos de organizacion"]
        self.listbox1.insert(0, *activos)
        self.listbox1.grid(row=3, column=0)


        self.listbox2 = GroupListbox(frame, width=35, height=28, group=lb_group)
        pasivos = ["Proveedores", "Acreedores varios", "Documentos a pagar",
                    "Intereses a pagar", "Obligaciones negociables",
                    "Prestamos a pagar", "Acreedores prendarios e hipotecarios",
                    "Adelantos en cuenta corriente", "Honorarios a pagar",
                    "Sueldos a pagar", "Anses a pagar",
                    "Retencion impuesto a las ganancias", "Retencion IVA",
                    "Dividendos", "Concepto cobrado por adelantado",
                    "Anticipo de clientes", "Cuentas por pagar", "Previsiones"]
        self.listbox2.insert(0, *pasivos)
        self.listbox2.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.listbox3 = GroupListbox(frame, width=35, height=28, group=lb_group)
        resultados = ['Gastos Luz','Descuento obtenido','Descuento otorgado',
                      'Interes otorgado','Interes obtenido', 'Ventas','CMV',
                      'Alquileres cobrados', 'Comision Cobrada', 'Impuestos',
                      'Alquileres pagados', 'Sueldos y jornales',
                      'Gastos generales', 'Comisiones pagadas',
                      'Publicidad', 'Seguros']

        self.listbox3.insert(0, *resultados)
        self.listbox3.grid(row=3, column=2)
        self.listbox1.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
        self.listbox2.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
        self.listbox3.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
        tk.Button(frame, text="aceptar", command=self.add_product).grid(row=4, column=1)


    def add_product(self):
        if rows:= (self.listbox1.selected_row or self.listbox2.selected_row):
            print(f"Ejecutado el if, row: '{rows}'")

        elif rows:= self.listbox3.selected_row:
            print(f"Ejecutado el elif, row: '{rows}'")

        else:
            print("Ejecutado el else, nada seleccionado")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Test(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]